# IOS Push Notification Sending Notification To Multiple Devices With Same Category

Tags: android, ios

in Android, google provides the Push Notification by Topic where a device registers for a certain topic example a music artist, and then all the devices registered with this topic will receive a push notification regarding this topic updates (without looping over the registration tokens in the server part)
is there a way to do this in IOS?

Comment: Create a channel like they do in Parse.com

Comment: can you please explain because i dont use sparse

Comment: You will have to write it in your backend service to allow the users to subscribe to certain groups/topics/channels. Then broadcast a push to APNS tokens of all subscribers from backend.

Comment: so its not available by default as in google. thank you